# DB data import - unmatched column count

Tags: mysql

My DB table has 12 columns. My import file has 12 columns. Yet I keep getting an error message saying  "Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1."
I've tried all sorts of formats for my import file but no success.
My import file first line is:

```
"michele","2021-01-01","2020Balance","10881.00","2","5","Fwd",
        "LQW","r","0","21","michele"  (12 columns)
```

My DB table is

```
user - date - Desc - amount - fracctno - toacctno - fracctname -
        toacctname - type - seqno - year - operator   (12 columns)
```

(There is no auto increment for the seqno.)

My input file is an Apache spreadsheet.

Thank you

Comment: How do you perform the import?

Comment: Click on Import, show as CSV format, show , (comma) for column separation and " (double quote) for column data start and end.

Comment: :facepalm: You should at least tell us which client you use...

Comment: Really don't know what you mean but if it helps, I'm using a database system provided by my web service provider - the only title I see is PHP MyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Got around the problem. My import file was an Apache Open Office Spreadsheet. It seems this was the problem.
I used a text document file with data format
"column1","column2", etc
and my data was imported without problem.
Thanks to all for helping!